Problem compiling [Select p from shudey.domain.mapping.properties.Property p] issue in query
I am currently using EclipseLink version 2.6.7. I have a entity class called Property and used the basic createNativequery api of EntityManager class as follows :
Query q1 = em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM MAP_PROP");

Now this gets compiled to an equivalent JPQL query and starts throwing the below error :
Problem compiling [Select p from shudey.domain.mapping.properties.Property p] [14,61] shudey.domain.mapping.properties.Property p' cannot be the first declaration of the FROM clause.

I think the grammar of the JPQL queries might have changed and we should be writing the queries in different manner is what I am assuming. Can someone tell me if there has been some changes oflate in the way the queries are written.
PS: This query used to work correctly with the older version of the eclipselink.

You are issuing an SQL native query - there is no conversion to a JPQL query or any compiling done within EclipseLink. Maybe show the full error and its stack trace to show where it is coming from exactly, as it shouldn't be from executing your q1 query
